# Происхождение слова "авоська"

Tags: этимология, лексика

У меня до сих пор дома лежит авоська, на редкость вместительная сумка. Происхождение названия кто-нибудь знает? Слово "авось" похоже, но особой связи не вижу.

Comment: Вы можете не видеть связи, если не застали времена тотального дефицита, когда поход в магазин был приключением (не очень веселым). Вот и надеялись люди "на авось"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово "авоська" было придумано Аркадием Райкиным в конце пятидесятых. В миниатюре обыгрывался персонаж, который брал сетку (так и называлась, "сетка" без "сумки") в карман "на авось", вдруг что попадётся.

Но само слово "авось" гораздо древнее.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю. какая авоська у Вас, а в моем детстве авоська - сетчатая сумочка (в фильме "Гостья из будущего" мальчик Коля носит в такой кефирные бутылки). Положил в карман или другую сумку - авось, пригодится. Вот тебе и авоська.

Comment: Похоже на правду.

Answer (score 0):

Авось < А+ось, Небось < Не (было) ось.

Ось - архаичная указательная частица, со знаением "вот", "это", "оно самое".
"Ось тебе раз!" - такое ещё недавно можно было услышать в деревнях.
С небось немного посложнее, там еще более хитрая фонетическая замена, но смысл тот же.